# Contador Visitas anti Bot Compartilhamento Facebook

Tags: php, contador

Criei um contador de visitas, mas, precisamos que não haja contagem alguma através das visitas para leitura dos bots, principalmente do facebook.

Este código é chamado via Ajax, após o usuário estar na página por **5** segundos.

Mesmo assim, ao compartilhar a página e o facebook ler as informações, ainda é contabilizado uma visita.

```
    $contador = &$_COOKIE['contador'.$album_id];
    if ( !$contador )
    {
        if (preg_match('~(bot|crawl)~i', $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"])) {
          echo 'bot';
        } else {
            if (
                strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], "facebookexternalhit/") !== false ||          
                strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], "Facebot") !== false
            )
            {
                echo 'bot';
            }
            else
            {
                setcookie('contador'.$album_id, true, time() + (  3600*24*7 ) ); 
               //insert no banco
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'ja visitou';
    }
}
```